# swipeable menu for windows 8 phone using visual studio 2013

Tags: menu, visual-studio-2013

I need to create swipeable tabs for windows 8 phone in visual studio 2013, cannot find any way around, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Just check Flick events, how they work and concentrate on horizaltalvelocity to identify left/right swipe.Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanxs, i figured out myself something